# Incrementing days in two different rows

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have two rows with date fields and I want to increment the days according to the entry I gave in the textbox field in the both rows on one go. And want to save that values in databse. I have tried the following code.

**code**

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lt" id="lt" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
                             </div>
 <table class="table-responsive">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="actual_engg[]" id="actual_engg" onchange="getdate()" value="<?php echo $subshow['actual_engg'];?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipd[]" id="ipd" value="<?php echo $subshow['indus_plan'];?>">
                                        </td>
     <div class="pull-right">

                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="tasksub" id="tasksub"  placeholder="Assign"/>
                      </div>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getdate() {
        var tt = document.getElementById('actual_engg').value;
        var ltt =document.getElementById('lt').value;
      console.log(ltt);
      console.log(tt);

        var date = new Date(tt);
        console.log(date);
        var newdate = new Date(date);
    console.log(newdate);

        newdate.setDate(+newdate.getDate() + +ltt);

        var dd = newdate.getDate();
        console.log(dd);
        var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = newdate.getFullYear();

        var someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y;
        document.getElementById('ipd').value = someFormattedDate;
        console.log(document.getElementById('ipd').value);
    }
                  </script>
```

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: I have tried the above code but only the onchange of the date is only working for the next row not the next subsequent rows. I need to save those values in database also.

Comment: I am not clear, you are talking about which row.